# Programatically removing a header context menu filter from RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid, filter

I've got a repeater I've bound to column names that are filtered, as they're applied (using sessions currently, I might change this to loop through the columns looking for filters now that I really know how the grid works).

I've got a button next to each filtered column name that is to remove the filter from the RadGrid.

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="repCorpFilters" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repFilters_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Current Filters:
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandName="removefilter" CommandArgument="corp" ImageUrl="../images/Delete.gif" />
                <asp:literal ID="litFilter" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem() %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                , 
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>


Protected Sub repFilters_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "removefilter"
            BindGrid(DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(products), e.CommandArgument), products), Nothing, _
                     CType(e.Item.FindControl("litFilter"), Literal).Text)
    End Select
End Sub


Private Sub BindGrid(ByVal prod As products, Optional ByVal cusipFilter As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal strRemoveFilter As String = Nothing)
    Dim dvCorp As DataView = CachedPartialCorp()
    If Not IsNothing(cusipFilter) Then
        isCusipFiltered = True
        dvCorp.RowFilter = "CUSIP IN " & cusipFilter
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(strRemoveFilter) Then
        Dim filters As List(Of String) = RemoveFilter("partialCorpFilters", strRemoveFilter)

        If filters.Count = 0 Then
            repCorpFilters.Visible = False
        Else
            repCorpFilters.DataSource = filters
            repCorpFilters.DataBind()
        End If

        For Each gc As GridColumn In dtgCorp.MasterTableView.Columns
            With gc
                If .IsBoundToFieldName(strRemoveFilter) Then
                    .CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter
                    .CurrentFilterValue = ""
                    .AndCurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter
                    .AndCurrentFilterValue = ""
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

    dtgCorp.DataSource = dvCorp
    dtgCorp.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Everything works fine except the actual removal of the filter from the RadGrid. Where I loop through the columns and find the correct column with the filter I'm trying to remove, I reset the filter drop downs and values, that works great! I can right click the header item, and the filter shows not filtered. But the data stays filtered! How do I tell the RadGrid to re-evaluate its new filtervalue based on the selected filters?

The juicy bit of the code I feel is here:

```
        For Each gc As GridColumn In dtgCorp.MasterTableView.Columns
            With gc
                If .IsBoundToFieldName(strRemoveFilter) Then
                    .CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter
                    .CurrentFilterValue = ""
                    .AndCurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.NoFilter
                    .AndCurrentFilterValue = ""
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

    dtgCorp.DataSource = dvCorp
    dtgCorp.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        For Each gc As GridColumn In dtg.MasterTableView.Columns
            With gc
                If .IsBoundToFieldName(strRemoveFilter) Then
                    dtg.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem)(0).FireCommandEvent(RadGrid.HeaderContextMenuFilterCommandName, _
                        New Triplet(strRemoveFilter, New Pair("NoFilter", ""), New Pair("NoFilter", "")))
                End If
            End With
        Next
```

This is the code that finally did it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using NeedDataSource binding for the grid instead of binding with DataBind() calls? Just invoke the Rebind() method of the grid in this case to clear the filter values. Also see how the filters are cleared on [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandcombo/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid).

Dick

Comment: I did try the Rebind() method, and to no avail: Exact same results. As for the demo, they clear the entire TableView's filterexpression with "RadGrid1.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = String.Empty". Which works great if you are totally clearing out the filters, but I need it to evaluate a new FilterExpression based on the currently chosen filters, after removing the selected one.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot be of further help here, you might contact Telerik posting in the forums on their site.